# How do I reformat my hard drive to NTFS?

Tags: ntfs

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday on my Windows Vista computer. Upon installing Ubuntu, I accidentally deleted everything and I guess I made my HD dedicated only to Ubuntu.

I inserted my Recovery Disk for my Windows Vista and upon trying to install it, it gave me this message:

```
Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS
```

So my question is how do I uninstall Ubuntu so my HD is back to NTFS Format so I can re-install my Windows Vista and then when I have all that installed, I'll re-install Ubuntu again, but this time, I'll install it alongside my Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the Ubuntu setup disk and use **GParted** to delete all partitions on the hard drive. You can then boot from the Windows setup disk and it will format the drive for you during installation, creating the necessary partitions for Windows to install.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your hard disk, no need to uninstall ubuntu. Just backup your personal files from linux. and then boot from the Windows CD/DVD. When you do that, there is options to format the HD as NTFS.

These links are useful : [link1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032760), [link2](http://www.hgst.com/support/faqs/how-format-my-drive-windows-only-ntfs), [link3](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/convert-hard-disk-partition-ntfs-format#1TC=windows-7), [link4](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/298634-32-format-ubuntu-drive-ntfs-relaod-windows)

Comment: I've got my files backed up already. And I'm not sure how to boot from the CD when it won't let me.

Comment: for booting the CD, you need to restart the pc, before it gets to the OS you push the magic key, which can be F2, F6, F11, or Del (you will see it written exactly when the pc turns on). You go to the system setup. There you can define the first boot device. You need to change it from Hard Disk to CD/DVD drive. Then save and exit

Comment: After this step the PC will search for boot from CD/DVD drive. Then you insert Windows CD/DVD and restart the pc. So it loads from the CD/DVD and installation will begin,

Comment: In my case, it shall be F8. So, do I disable the HD and only make it run the CD/DVD ? or it don't matter ?

Comment: yeah, bring the CD/DVD as first option, and the others come after.

Comment: OK I'll try that and hopefully it'll work. Fingers.... crossed!!