# Windows and Linux broken after attempted bootloader fix

Tags: bootloader

First, I messed up and I'm not even sure if this is still the correct site for this but here I am. This is what happened:

Two days ago I booted into Windows 10 which wanted to install updates while shutting down. I did that and the next day my bootloader was overwritten (common problem). I tried a few ways in order to fix it, none of which worked. My last attempt was to reinstall Ubuntu via USB-stick which did not work (I don't exactly recall the error message, but it was unable to write to the selected partition). In the end I just said f*ck it and wanted to reset both Windows and Ubuntu. The problem now is that when booting into Windows it says that it is repairing my harddrive. This failed because it did not have enough space on the Windows partition according to the error message.

**tl:dr** Ubuntu bootloader is gone, Windows can't repair itself because there is not enough space on the partition (or something like that).

Now I am here because I don't want to make it worse. I don't care if I loose all my data, I just want a clean install of Linux and Windows 10. If I have to choose, I choose Linux.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NJnQ.png) is what gparted says. Here the upper disk is an SSD and the lower one is an HDD.

Right now I'm not sure what other info you guys need, so I'll leave it at that.

But thanks already.

Comment: perform a [clean installation of Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-to-perform-a-clean-install-or-reinstall-of/aef0ae63-2117-41ee-a8ea-4a3181625b08?page=5) where you delete all partitions created so far. I suggest you keep data partitions if data is important. Now with Win10 alone in your system, reinstall Ubuntu as before to make it dual-boot.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it good to install Windows after or before Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466418/is-it-good-to-install-windows-after-or-before-ubuntu) and [How do I reformat my hard drive to NTFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424357/)